# Remove null pointers from key array Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a class with a key, "elementFileArray", with pointers to objects in another class.
It may happen that one of these objects is deleted and the pointer remains there. I notice that the pointer just becomes "null" when I read the array. So:

```
self.collectionElementArray = (collectionElement?["elementFileArray"] as? [AnyObject])!
```

has "PFObject, PFObject, ... , null , ... , PFObject".
I am trying ideally to delete that null from the array on the server. However it doesn't seem possible because I have no object Id. In the worst scenario I could delete it in this local array, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out `nil`:

```
self.collectionElementArray.filter() { $0 != nil }
```

Comment: "$0 is NSNull" seems to work. However how do you negate is?